# Changing Color real time using OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm currently given an assignment about changing a certain color in real-time using OpenCV, I am able to configure to display the camera, and to detect certain colors in the range, but stuck in changing the color to another one. For example here in my code I'm detecting red color and wanted to change it to blue.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int RoboX = 300;
int RoboY = 10;
Mat VRobo(Mat gbr, int arah);
int main()
{
    VideoCapture kameraku(0);
    Mat image;
    Mat image2;
    Mat hsv;
    Mat BW;
    Mat element;
    namedWindow("Kamera", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("Convert", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while (1) {
        kameraku >> image;
        kameraku >> image2;
        imshow("Kamera", image);
        cvtColor(image2, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 60, 60), Scalar(5, 255, 255), BW);
        element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5, 5));
        erode(BW, BW, element);
        erode(BW, BW, element);
        erode(BW, BW, element);
        dilate(BW, BW, element);
        dilate(BW, BW, element);
        dilate(BW, BW, element);
        imshow("Convert", BW);
        char c = (char)waitKey(25);
        if (c == 27) break;
    }
    kameraku.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

here's the python code:

````
import numpy as np

# Load the aerial image and convert to HSV colourspace
image = cv.imread("aerial.png")
hsv=cv.cvtColor(image,cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define lower and uppper limits of what we call "brown"
brown_lo=np.array([10,0,0])
brown_hi=np.array([20,255,255])

# Mask image to only select browns
mask=cv.inRange(hsv,brown_lo,brown_hi)

# Change image to red where we found brown
image[mask>0]=(0,0,255)

cv.imwrite("result.png",image)```
````

Comment: show the input. show the result. show what's wrong with it.

Comment: did you import cv

Comment: did you inspect your mask to see that it contained white areas, i.e actually thresholded on brown?

Comment: yes, I already import CV, and yes i already inspect my mask the see if it contained white areas